# Filter order data to rows

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-docs

I need to make sheet that will contain each order code, address, quantity and dates in one row for each order code.
I have sheet "Data" with orders (Address ID, Product code, quantity and Order ID)  and i need to put it in other sheet "Export" in specific order. Is there a way to do it with functions or script?

I made test spreadsheet so everyone can see preview of what i need: [test sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_vI9cYaMLmGCGPu0HTDqwZrbLMjILhr6CeWDg7WkKO0/edit#gid=1187883109)

For example i have Address ID A001, i need to get each code and quantity from this address ID and put in row, in test spreadsheet i made example.

Sorry if I am asking too much, but i need some help or advice :)

Made picture so it would be easier to understand:
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XbDW.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operation you need is called "unpivot" and has a couple of possible solutions, some of them purely functional and some utilizing Google Apps Script. Search for "unpivot" to explore them. Here goes one of possible functional solutions. It is simplified compared to your precise needs because I am not sure which of your headers ("dimensions") are unique. I'm assuming here that only the product code and address id are unique, because it looks like this in the data.

Make a new worksheet and put the formula below in A1:

```
=arrayformula(
  split(
    transpose(
      split(
        concatenate(
          arrayformula(Data!$A$5:$A & "|" &Data!$C$3:$G$3 & "\"
          )
        );
      "\")
    );
    "|")
  )
```

Then put another formula in C1:

```
=arrayformula(
  vlookup(A1:A; Data!$A$5:$G; match(B1:B; Data!$C$3:$G$3; 0)+2; 0)
 )
```

This will give you the rudimentary idea of how to construct first the list of all possible combinations of dimension values (Code, Address ID in this case) and then fill in possible dependent values using VLOOKUP. Then you can use more VLOOKUPS to add more columns as needed.

Comment: Thanks for information!
But atm i am having error with this formula, because i have too many data (Text result of CONCATENATE is longer than the limit of 50000 characters)
What can i do to avoid it?

Comment: One thing you can do is "divide and conquer", i.e. make several formulas that operate on different parts of your data and join the results. But I suspect that in this case it may be worth it to research script solutions.

Comment: I see. Any clues how to do it in script language? Don't want to split data in many spreadsheets :/